# How to jump after } in c# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can not find anything on this.

During coding (not debugging) I would like to jump from position 1 or 2 to position 3 after hitting a key or shortcut (without needing to use the arrow keys). This is an example scenario:

```
public int Something()
{
    int x = 5; //position 1
    return x; //position 2

} //position 3
// position 4 would also be fine as destination
```

In words described: "Move cursor (insertion point) after the next `}` ".

Is there anything out of the box in visual studio?

EDIT: this question is about fast and comfortable coding thus avoiding using the mouse or anything that requires moving hands out of the "comfort zone".

Comment: position 4 would not be possible as it has no executable code (try setting a break point on a comment...) - also, it is never reached since after position 3 control is returned to the caller. You can either go with @Steve's suggestion or set a break point on position 3 and hit F5.

Comment: Ctrl + F3 on the `}`.

Comment: ReSharper has the ability to move between methods / properties within a class using the `ALT`+`UP/DOWN` shortcut.

Comment: @oerkelenes 
i meant not during debugging. I meant during just typing code.

Comment: Point and click works for me :)

Comment: @DanielMay
This would involve arrow keys which i want to avoid. I want to avoid moving hands out of the "comfort zone".

Comment: @user3584269 Sure - you can re-map any of the shortcuts in ReSharper.

Comment: If you had a `public int SomethingElse() //position 5` at the bottom of your example, would position 5 be acceptable?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain
No, i just want to jump out of { } and continue with new code.

Comment: I don't see a good way to do it, you might just want to find or [write your own](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/ide/extensions/overview) Visual Studio Extension to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could toggle a bookmark on every line that you want to jump by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>:

[image]

Then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to move to that line.

[image]

More details: [Setting Bookmarks in Code.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/setting-bookmarks-in-code)

Comment: not possible with bookmarks. I want to jump to the end of the { } in order to place the cursor to continue coding as fast as possible.
Its about just avoiding to have to hit the down arrow 1,2,3 or 4 times in order to go behind the }

Comment: @user3584269 What's your mean. You can quickly return to a specific location and jump back and forth between locations by using bookmarks. What could be more easier than this behavior?

Comment: @S.Akbari he wants to jump to a location to add new code, he does not want to pre-navigate there every time to set up the bookmark once he adds a new method

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>}</kbd> will take you to the nearest }. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> does incremental search, and jumps to next location that matches the search.

Comment: I upvoted this answer. It is the closest to what i want to do.
But it selects the } so an 'Esc' is needed, and an 'Enter'. And on my keyboard (not english) i have to press 'alt gr' + n in order to get the }. This makes it to many keys. (I did notice that i can hit Ctrl+I twic and it will automatically insert the } - IF the } was the last thing i searched.)
I am still trying this out.

Comment: `Down` key can replace `Esc`, `Enter`. Also I recommend using English US (not English international) keyboard for programming. I bet there are a lot of times where you have to use `AltGr` that you would not have to if the keyboard were English US.

Comment: it would require me to use arrow keys which i want to avoid. Still good to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the menu Tools->Options and go to the section Environment->Keyboard there are many keybindings you can set. One that may work for what you want is `Edit.NextMethod` and `Edit.PreviousMethod` (EDIT: Nevermind, from your comment, this goes to "position 5" I mentioned).

Check all of the options under the `Edit.` namespace there may be a more appropriate one for your needs.

Comment: checked under Edit. Its overwhelming.
As you suggested to create my own extension, i googled about it. For now i am not able to do that.
If someone creates this, i hope he shares it with us. I can imagine i am not the first one who had this idea.